# Google Spreadsheet Queries : How to get the first record of each group?

Tags: google-sheets

Sample database:[Stored as Google spreadsheet]

> - Timestamp=======|=Contact No=|=Bill=======|
> - ===============|===========|==-========|
> - 11/7/2014 2:46:29 |    9332261982 | 13.0305472 |
> - 15/6/2014 2:46:29 |    9332261982 | 14.0305472 |
> - 22/5/2014 2:46:29 |    9332261982 | 16.0305472 |
> - 11/4/2014 2:46:29 |    9332261982 | 20.0305472 |
> - 15/7/2014 2:46:29 |    9916901970 | 13.0305472 |
> - 1/6/2014 2:46:29  |    9916901970 | 14.0305472 |
> - 12/5/2014 2:46:29 |    9916901970 | 16.0305472 |
> - 20/4/2014 2:46:29 |    9916901970 | 20.0305472 |

I need:

> - Timestamp=======|=Contact No=|=Bill=======|
> - ===============|===========|===========|
> - 11/7/2014 2:46:29 |    9332261982 | 13.0305472 |
> - 15/7/2014 2:46:29 |    9916901970 | 13.0305472 |

So I have 3 columns Time stamp(Column - A), Contact Number(Column - B) and Bill amount(Column - C) in a Google Spreadsheet.
I need a big query(or a query that I can use with Google Spreadsheet) that can fetch me the most recent bill amount by time stamp for each contact if I pass that contact in the query(as a where clause - as in where B contains XXX or B contains YYY).

So far by checking other Stack overflow links and Google search I have come up with something like this:

```
select * where B contains 9332261982 order by A DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0
```

or

```
select A,B,C where B contains 9332261982 or B contains 9916901970 order by A DESC
```

So how to marge this and get the Query I want?

Comment: Are you using BigQuery the product, or are you using Google Spreadsheets? It's not clear.

Comment: I am using Google Spreadsheets and the queries associated with it. It looks like big Query, however not that flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BigQuery I would do something like:

```
Select A,B,C FROM
(Select * 
, Row_Number() Over(Partition By B Order by A Desc) as RNB
From yourtable)
Where RNB=1
```

An alternative (if you don't have window functions) would be using some string manipulations and max.

1. create a column D by concatenating the date column with the value column (A_C) so you'll get something like: 2014-10-29 23:15:2__000012345 (note the 0 padding so the resulted string will be of same length)
2. run a simple aggregate of select B,MAX(D) E from...
3. Sub-string the new E column.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer N.N. I gave it a try. So the sql breaks when i try to append it to the Google spreadsheet URL. 

For example:

[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<My Spreadsheet key>/gviz/tq?tqx=out:html&headers=1&gid=917911740&tq=select * where B contains 9916901970)

This returns me a table of data. But when I try the query above it just goes crazy.

Comment: For more reference, I'm trying to use the query syntax that is described here.[link](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)